# Ajax always returning null value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm new on PHP and now i'm learning about how to use AJAX, i just want to get the return value that passed from PHP(webservice.php) to JS. I dont know why it always return null value when im trying to alert it with the "alert(result)" on my JS Login function.

I'm sorry for my bad English, hope u guys understand what i mean

HTML :

```
<input class="button btnlogin" type="button" class="alt" id="btn_submit_data" value="Log In" onclick="login()" />
```

JS :

```
function login() {
    var id = document.getElementById('login_email').value;
    var pass = document.getElementById('login_pass').value;
    $.get("http://localhost/project/dist/bin/webservice.php", {
        ajx: "login",
        email: id,
        password: pass
    }, function (result) {
        if (result == true) {
            window.location.href = "http://localhost/project/index.php";
        } else {
            alert(result);//This is where i want to get the value but it always returning the null value
        }
    });
}
```

PHP (connection.php) :

```
<?php
    session_start();

    function getConnection(){
        $servername ="127.0.0.1";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $database = "project";
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$database);
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        return $conn;
    }
    getconnection();
?>
```

PHP (webservice.php) :

```
<?php
    include 'connection.php';

    if($_GET['ajx'] == "login"){
        $email = $_GET['email'];
        $password = $_GET['password'];
        Login($email,$password);
    }

    function Login($email,$password){
        return $email;
    }
?>
```

Comment: return something from the if {} in your webservice.php

Comment: I think you need: `return Login($email,$password);`

Comment: your returning `return $userpass;` but `$userpass` is not defined

Comment: already, null value always returned

Comment: ok let me try @CodingYoshi

Comment: Try first to return a basic json `echo '{test:"test"}' ` to see if the server respond as well.

Comment: echo value on webservice.php, eg: echo 1;

Comment: `echo Login($email,$password);` would be the simplest change to your `webservice.php` - though, it wouldn't be `true` it'd be the passed in email, which is always truthy regardless, so `if (result == true) {` would then always be true ... currently, you're checking `if ('' == true)`, i.e. an empty string, which is falsey

Comment: please enter your full form markup

Comment: @RajanBenipuri - why would you need that? the problem is in the php code

Comment: Because, I thought there are some errors in the jQuery code as well.

Comment: Found the problem! like what u thought @RajanBenipuri the problem is on my jquery, its on my IF statement. Thanks also jaromanda X!

Answer (score 0):

Because your PHP code does not return anything. What you get in your browser is defined by what PHP returns in output buffer.
As many said you should use:

```
$output = Login($email,$password);
echo json_encode($output);
```

You should also include:

```
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script) question.